# How to display a specific row of a table in dash

Tags: matplotlib, graph, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I'm trying to display a single row from my dash table, but the thing is that I've tried everything and it displays the complete dataframe, anyone coould help me here?

```
html.Div([

        dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns[2:10]])

     ]),
```

Comment: I think there are two ways to do this: a) create a data frame with only specific rows in advance, b) limit it in the `dashTable()`, or c) set a filter by default in `dashTable()`, but I think this is the easiest with method B. `df.iloc[[x],2:10]`

Comment: How many rows do you have in your dataframe?